# Adding a Newline

Tags: c#, string

The code below adds the characters `\r\n` to my string variable but once the string is returned the Newline is ignored.

Here is a snippet of the returned string: **Mondavi\r\nrms_processtype**

And here is the code where I add a Newline:

```
 char[] charsToTrim = { ',', ' ' };
 feed = feed.TrimEnd(charsToTrim) + Environment.NewLine;
```

Here's the code that error's when it attempts to read the "feed" variable

```
var dict = feed.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .SelectMany(s => s.Split('|')).ToDictionary(t => t.Split(',')[0], t => t.Split(',')[1]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'code that error's'? Which error are you getting? Maybe the problem is that one of the separator string is a sub-string of the other one and this confuses `Split()`?

Comment: I get Index Out of Bounds on the last part t.Split(',')[1]

Comment: your snippet string doesn't have `,` in it hence `t.Split(',')` has 1 elements and `t.Split(',')[1]` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`